# Does $\sum_{n=0}^N{1\over\sqrt{n!}}$ have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just out of curiosity, does the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^N{1\over\sqrt{n!}}$$  have a closed form for $N<\infty$ or eventually $N\to\infty$ ? I cannot find it anywhere and it does not resemble any function expansion I can now recall.

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: Approximate value, in case others were wondering: [3.46951](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N[Sum[1%2F%28n!%29^%281%2F2%29%2C+{n%2C+0%2C+Infinity}]%2C+10])

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how do you know? Or how can you disprove it? Is this sum somehow important that somebody cares?

Comment: Calculate to many decimal places and check at http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: Cf. to [A248761](http://oeis.org/A248761), which is this value minus one with ~100 digits available. As far as I can see, there is no available literature on this sum.

Comment: When I was a schoolboy, trying to make a tiny discovery, I numerically calculated with high precision similar sums of exotic series with simple written terms, and then compared them with simple expressions obtained from known constants. I did no discovery. :-)

Comment: @Will Jagy Tried and found nothing (nice site btw).

Comment: @All Now with a rested mind I do realize that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\alpha^{n+1}\over\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle$$ is something called a coherent state in physics (unnormalized) so it is certainly important. Nonetheless, this does not answer my question.